# How to create a database using libpq-fe

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a new database using C code and libpq-fe.h

The problem is taht there's literally not a single example on the internet to show you how to do so, including the docs.

If I try to specify the database name that I want to create in the connection I get an error, if I don't, I think it connects automatically to postgres database.

But I want to create and connect to a new database, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to create a database is to first connect to another database, then run `CREATE DATABASE` there. That's what the `postgres` database is there for. So do this:

- connect to database `postgres`
- execute the `CREATE DATABASE` statement
- disconnect from `postgres`
- connect to the newly created database

Answer (score 0):

any particular reason you want to create the database from the app?
I would use dBeaver, best tool for database manipulations.
https://dbeaver.io/download/

anyways have you looked at this:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_c_cpp.htm

I'd connect using that and then create a database regularly with an SQL command:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html